# Angular 11 ,loading ~150 highcharts in one page , performance is bad, ui freeze

Tags: performance, highcharts, angular11

I'm creating line highchart(other component) in the table- component for each row, highchart div idcontainer=rowID .
in the case of filter or table loading the screen is freeze till chart is finished to draw.
without charts it works perfectly.
please help

Comment: It depends on multiple factors, I have mentioned one with higher wattage.
- How many data sources are there/API hits? response from server ? Data hits?
- How many components have you created?

How you are planning to show 150 Highcharts in single page?

Comment: One Api that return all the data in one moment and very fast. then I create a mat-table where each row has data and one of the cell is trend chart. it should displayed for each row in the table.I create a component app-history-trend , that I put to this cell.

Comment: <ng-container  matColumnDef="last7daysTrend">
     <th style="padding-left: 63px;" mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Trend</th>
     <td mat-cell class="td-history-trend-width display-flex"  *matCellDef="let element;;let i=index">  
         <app-history-trend  [idChart]="i+1+chartPriorityID" [data]="element.measures.dataPointsLocal" ></app-history-trend> 
       </td>
   </ng-container>

Comment: Many things could have an impact on it. Are you able to reproduce this issue on some online editor that I could debug on?

Comment: Thanks, i have a problem to share it due to security issue but I will show what I'm doing 1. create mat table  2. for each row loading <chart-comp> 3. every filter i'n doing on this table redraw the chart again..... it takes a time and freeze the screen. i tried to use cdk- virtual-scroll  but it was not good as well. :(

Answer (score 0):

Showing 150+ highcharts is not an issue.
Check this URL it loads 128 graphs in no time. [Link](https://www.highcharts.com/studies/performance.php?seriesType=line&markers=on&chartCount=128&seriesPerChart=1&pointsPerSeries=16&chartWidth=250&libSource=https%3A%2F%2Fcode.highcharts.com%2F2.2%2Fhighcharts.js)

1. As you mentioned that you are using highcharts in mat table, avoid doing this.(you can give same tabular experience with basic code use ng-for loop)
2. If you have very complex charts with multiple series and points per series, visit boost module of Highcharts.

Comment: Thanks!! why avoid it? what is baic code? you mean to use not mat- table table and to use regular table?

Comment: Can you simulate this issue any online code editor, just add sample component with its code.